# Can anyone explain parameters in CodeSmith SchemaExplorer.ViewSchema Constructor?

Tags: c#, codesmith

From CodeSmith API help
[C#]
public ViewSchema(
   DatabaseSchema DatabaseSchema,
   string String,
   string String,
   DateTime DateTime,
   ExtendedProperty[] ExtendedProperty[]
);

Parameters
database
name
owner
dateCreated
extendedProperties

I can see what the first 3 parameters mean.

But what is the purpose of last 2 parameters dateCreated and extendProperties?

Is there any sample of using this constructor I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter you pass in the DatabaseSchema.

The second parameter you pass in the name of the view.

The third parameter is the owner of the view (E.G dbo).

The fourth property is a DateTime which represents when the view was created or when you created it, you can pass in DateTime.Now.

The fifth property is the ExtendedProperty Collection for the view, this stores any extra metadata that you want to access in your templates.

Thanks

-Blake Niemyjski